What is the domain of Caputo fractional derivative? Is zero included or excluded?
Caputo fractional derivative is defined as
$$^CD^\alpha f(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}\int_0^x\frac{f^{(n)}(t)}{(x-t)^{\alpha-n+1}}dt$$
Where $n$ is the ceiling of $\alpha$.
I found some papers define the domain of the definition to be $x\in[0,\infty[$ and other papers define the domain to be $x\in]0,\infty[$.
So I want to know if zero should be included or excluded from the domain. And if it should be excluded, then how one could compute the value $f^\frac{1}{2}(0)$ for some function $f(x)$?

Why is $x = 0$ excluded from the domain ($x = \left] 0,\, \infty \right[$)?
Let's just see what happens if we substitute $x = 0$ into the definition you gave:
\begin{align*}
f^{\left( \alpha \right)}\left( x \right) = \operatorname{^{C}D}^{\alpha}\left[ f\left( x \right) \right] &= \frac{1}{\Gamma\left( \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil - \alpha \right)} \cdot \int\limits_{0}^{x} \frac{f^{\left( \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil \right)}\left( t \right)}{\left( x - t \right)^{\alpha - \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil + 1}}\, \operatorname{d}t\\
f^{\left( \alpha \right)}\left( 0 \right) &= \frac{1}{\Gamma\left( \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil - \alpha \right)} \cdot \int\limits_{0}^{0} \frac{f^{\left( \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil \right)}\left( t \right)}{\left( 0 - t \right)^{\alpha - \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil + 1}}\, \operatorname{d}t\\
f^{\left( \alpha \right)}\left( 0 \right) &= \frac{1}{\Gamma\left( \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil - \alpha \right)} \cdot 0\\
f^{\left( \alpha \right)}\left( 0 \right) &= 0\\
\end{align*}
So "the" caputo derivative at $x = 0$ would be equal to $0$.
Why is this a problem? We know $\operatorname{^{C}D}_{x}^{\frac{1}{2}}\operatorname{^{C}D}_{x}^{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}$, so $\operatorname{^{C}D}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left[ \operatorname{^{C}D}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left[ x \right] \right] = \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}x = 1$ (you can easily see this using $\operatorname{^{C}D}^{\alpha}\left[ x^{b} \right] = \frac{\Gamma\left( b + 1 \right)}{\Gamma\left( b - \alpha + 1 \right)} \cdot x^{b - \alpha}$). So let's take $f\left( x \right) = x$, we get:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{^{C}D}_{x}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left[ \operatorname{^{C}D}_{x}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left[ f\left( x \right) \right] \right] \mid_{x = 0} &= \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}x \mid_{x = 0}\\
\operatorname{^{C}D}_{x}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left[ \operatorname{^{C}D}_{x}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left[ f\left( x \right) \right] \right] \mid_{x = 0} &= 1 \mid_{x = 0}\\
0 &= 1 \quad\unicode{x21af}\\
\end{align*}
This contradicts itself, so $x = 0$ can't be in the domain.
Reference:

Power rule for caputo derivative: "Remarks on the Caputo fractional derivative" > paragraph $3$ from the Faculty of Applied Mathematics, Silesian University of Technology. https://minut.polsl.pl/articles/B-23-001.pdf


How to fix this problem?
There are a few options here.

One could define the lower limit in the integral of the caputo fractional derivative as a selectable constant $a < x$. You see this quite often marked with the $a$ in ${_{a}^{\text{C}}\operatorname{D}}_{x}^{\alpha}$.
You could use some type of fractional derivative / intergal, such as the $\text{RL}$-type (also note: in $\text{RL}$ there is also the variable $a$ at the lower limit).
You could use an equivalent formulation from other fractional derivatives as a definition for the $\text{C}$-type fractional derivative.
...

Using $\int\limits_{a}^{x}$
Let's say
\begin{align*}
{_{a}^{\text{C}}\operatorname{D}}_{x}^{\alpha}\left[ f\left( x \right) \right] &= \frac{1}{\Gamma\left( \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil - \alpha \right)} \cdot \int\limits_{a}^{x} \frac{f^{\left( \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil \right)}\left( t \right)}{\left( x - t \right)^{\alpha - \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil + 1}}\, \operatorname{d}t,
\end{align*}
then the domain would change to $x \in \left( a,\, \infty \right)$ aka for $a \to -\infty$ we would get the domain $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
Note: There are many different formulas for the caputo fractional derivative, each with their own advantages.
References:

Reference for formula and domain: "A new Definition of Fractional Derivative without Singular Kernel" > paragraph $2$ by Caputo and Fabrizio. https://www.naturalspublishing.com/files/published/0gb83k287mo759.pdf

Using other fractional derivatives / integrals
E.G. you could use the Riemann-Liouville Operator (a fractional integral):
\begin{align*}
{_{a}^{\text{RL}}\operatorname{D}_{x}^{\alpha}}\left[ f\left( x \right) \right] = \frac{1}{\Gamma\left( -\alpha \right)} \cdot \int\limits_{a}^{x} \frac{f\left( t \right)}{\left( x - t \right)^{\alpha + 1}} \operatorname{d}t \tag{$\alpha \leq 0$}\\
\end{align*}
or as differintegral:
\begin{align*}
{_{a}^{\text{RL}}\operatorname{D}_{x}^{\alpha}}\left[ f\left( x \right) \right] = \frac{1}{\Gamma\left( \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil - \alpha \right)} \cdot \frac{\operatorname{d}^{\left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil}}{\operatorname{d}x^{\left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil}} \int\limits_{a}^{x} \frac{f\left( t \right)}{\left( x - t \right)^{\alpha - \left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil + 1}} \operatorname{d}t\\
\end{align*}
The domain would be $x \in \left( a,\, \infty \right)$ (for $a \to -\infty$ it would be $x \in \mathbb{R}$).
References:

Derivation: Weisstein, Eric W. "Fractional Integral." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalIntegral.html
Possible / Most popular Definition: Weisstein, Eric W. "Riemann-Liouville Operator." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Riemann-LiouvilleOperator.html
Popular differintegrals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differintegral#Standard_definitions

Formula in terms of other fractional derivatives
Although the derivation for the $\text{RL}$-type and $\text{C}$-type fractional derivative may look quite different, but they are closely related. The following applies:
\begin{align*}
{_{a}^{\text{C}}\operatorname{D}}_{x}^{\alpha}\left[ f\left( x \right) \right] &= {_{a}^{\text{RL}}\operatorname{D}}_{x}^{\alpha}\left[ f\left( x \right) \right] - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\left\lceil \alpha \right\rceil - 1}\left[ \frac{f^{\left( k \right)}\left( a \right)}{\Gamma\left( k - \alpha + 1 \right)} \cdot \left( x - a \right)^{k - \alpha} \right]\\
\end{align*}
Reference:

Connection between $\text{RL}$-type and $\text{C}$-type fractional derivative: "On Riemann and Caputo fractional differences" > Property $3$ by Thabet Abdeljawad. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S089812211100188X


Thanks for your help
